# MVC multiple select List not showing default values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Been working on this issue for a few hours now, maybe I'm missing something simple here, but no matter what I try I can't get the default selected items to work.

The controller function:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Room room = db.Rooms.Find(id);
    if (room == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    List<int> allowedMods = new List<int> {1, 2};
    List<keyval> allMods = new List<keyval>
    {
        new keyval(1,"A"),
        new keyval(2,"B"),
        new keyval(3,"C")
    };
    MultiSelectList multiList = new MultiSelectList(allMods, "ID", "Name", allowedMods);
    ViewBag.mods = multiList;
    return View(room);
}
```

Simple helper class keyval:

```
public class keyval
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public keyval() { }
    public keyval(int ID, string Name)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

The view:

```
@model X.Models.Room

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Room</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Moderators Allowed", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.ListBox("mods", ViewBag.mods as MultiSelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Relevant generated Html:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <select class="form-control" id="mods" multiple="multiple" name="mods">
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

I've tried so many different variations and when I submit the form I do get the new list of selected items, However the default values is not working for me.

I would really appreciate help on this issue.

Comment: Maybe I should also mention that when I debug the view page, I do see the "SelectedValues" list, and it does contains the 2 key values. but the rendered page has no default values set.

Comment: Are you able to use ListBoxFor?

Comment: @JB06 yes I've tried, it didn't work as well.
`@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.ModeratorsAllowed, mlist, new { id = "mods", Multiple = "multiple", @class = "form-control" })`
does the same thing

Comment: With the ListBoxFor helper, you don't have to specify the multiple or id attributes. Is mlist a model property? If so, you need to use it like: Model.mlist

Comment: @JB06 mlist is not a model property, it's simply the a
`MultiSelectList mlist = ViewBag.mods as MultiSelectList;`
BTW, I've tried:
`@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.ModeratorsAllowed, mlist.SelectedValues, new { id = "mods", Multiple = "multiple", @class = "form-control" })`.
but it fails

Comment: Maybe I'll make myself a little clearer: I want to be able to edit the model property called `ModeratorsAllowed`. to do so I want to be able to see which items were already selected.

Comment: Can you update your question with the generated html of the listbox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91523/discussion-between-liranbo-and-jb06).

Comment: I can't use chat, it's blocked on my work network...but it looks like the values for your list are using the Name property of the list, not the Id

Comment: Sorry, updated, I was playing with some of the values in the controller

Comment: If you post your form and by any reason you want to again render the form, the selected items are lost and you have to some how re-init tour mutliselect object.

Comment: @persian Developer, thanks I know, that isn't the case tho.
I didn't post the form yet, this is how it loads for the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of your listbox is the same as the name of your ViewBag property that holds the list, there is a strange bug with ViewBag that causes things to not render properly if this is the case. Try changing ViewBag.mods to ViewBag.moderators or something other than ViewBag.mods.

Tested using your code and that corrects the problem for me.

Comment: WOW, I just.... can't believe this is real.
I've spent almost all day on this issue.
Many many thanks!

Comment: Yet another reason I always advocate view models :)

Comment: Hmm, if you mean to use a strongly type html helper then I am using it.
but I only have the selected list and not the full list of users. So I don't see how I can use a ListBoxFor in here...